# Does WCF client support OCSP stapling?

Tags: c#, wcf, security, ssl, ocsp

I'm calling a SOAP service with a .Net WCF proxy client class. Is it possible to improve CRL checking performance by using OCSP stapling?

I have looked at the `X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication.RevocationMode` property but that only supports the following values, with no mention of OCSP.

`NoCheck`   No revocation check is performed on the certificate.

`Offline`   A revocation check is made using a cached certificate revocation list (CRL).

`Online`    A revocation check is made using an online certificate revocation list (CRL).